# implemeting excel formula IFERROR from python using xlswriter

Tags: python, excel-formula, xlsxwriter

I am writing a python code to process some results and put the results in excel. The excel file is made to have excel formulae in it. I am using xlswriter module to write the excel formula in the python code. I couldn't implement excel formula "IFERROR" in the python code. the syntax is as shown below but this doesn't work in excel. The formula doesn't appear meaning it doesn't get transferred from python to excel.

```
formellen_utnyttelse='=IFERROR({sheet}!{col3}{row1}/{sheet}!{col4}{row1};0)'.format(sheet=hub_sheet,row1=hubitem_rowcount+1,col3=xl_col_to_name(totalloadvaluename_col),col4=xl_col_to_name(inplacecapacityname_col))
worksheet_hub_timehistory.write_formula(hubitem_rowcount,inplaceutilisationname_col,formellen_utnyttelse)
```

Help much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

The formula should works expected in XlsxWriter, see the example below. You just need to ensure your `format()` function is correct. Maybe print out the result of `format()` and see if it is correct.

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write(0, 0, '=IFERROR(A2/B2,"Error in calculation")')
worksheet.write(1, 0, 1)
worksheet.write(1, 1, 0)

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: I found out what was the error. If you see my code that I posted as a question. I have used ; (semicolon) (i.e. IFERROR(A/B;0) )as we used in excel but it looks like while using xlswriter, one has to use , (comma) as in your code (i.e. IFERROR(A/B),0)

Comment: Yes. Formulas need to follow US Excel syntax. See this section of the XlsxWriter docs: [Non US Excel functions and syntax](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#non-us-excel-functions-and-syntax)